# Android Expanding Toast cause crash

Tags: android, toast, onpause

Hey I am getting an crash on the code below. I am trying to expand a Toast for a certan amount of time, and "kill" the Toast when the `onPause` is runned.
What am I doing wrong? The crash occures when i add `timer.cancel()` in the  `onPause`

```
private boolean checkInternetConnection() {



    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    // test for connection
    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {

        splashTread.start();
        return true;
    } else {



        timer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000)
        {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {toast.show();}
            public void onFinish() {toast.cancel();}

        }.start();



        return false;
    }
}



@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    finish();
timer.cancel():
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
    timer.cancel():



}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do. The app crashes because the timer = null. The timer has never been run or set.

Add this in both onDestroy and onPause:

```
if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();

    }
```